# How redirect all page extensions to custom 404 not found page in an asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a custom page in my asp.net project. I created a page for 404 not found errors. Here is a part in web config:

```
<customErrors  mode="On" defaultRedirect="Errors.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

When I write to web browser like "**(websitename)/asdfasdf.aspx**", I can see to custom error page which I created, but when I write "**(websitename)/asdfasdf**", I see "**Server Error / 404 - File or directory not found.**" page (Default Error page).

Do you know how can I redirect all page extensions to my custom error page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I am using hosting to my website, so in hosting there was a setting to set 404 not found page. So, It solved.

Answer (score 0):

In the Application_Error in global.asax file, find the server error code and redirect to corresponding page based on error code:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Clear();

        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

        if (httpException != null)
        {
            string redirectToPage;
            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                // page not found
                case 404:
                    redirectToPage = "(websitename)/PageNotFoundError.aspx";
                    break;
                default:
                    redirectToPage = "(websitename)/GeneralError.aspx";
                    break;
            }

            Response.Redirect(redirectToPage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got same result with this code. I guess, I have to add .aspx extension automatically to url. Like: If user write /sfsfsfdf , system will add automatically .aspx ... Is it possible?

Comment: system automatically does error handling based on the code written in Application_Error on global.asax file. Have you tried to debug the program after you type the wrong url? does it go to the above method? if not then try it out and see what is happening there. May be you have to change something after you see what is the result of debugging