# Asp.net Display 404 Screen for any 404 error

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, http-status-code-404

I have Asp.net website (Webforms). I want to Display custom page for 404 errors. I have following entry in web.config file:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404error.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

But this only redirects all pages with extensions. But Extension-less URLs like [http://website/abc/123] are not considered as page request, therefore there's no mapping for 404 custom page display. Instead I get browser generated 404 error page.

I have also tried to use Global.asax file's **Application_Error** method, but this error doesn't fall in this method for this case.

Please suggest to capture such 404 exceptions.

Note: I have read the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794829/how-redirect-all-page-extensions-to-custom-404-not-found-page-in-an-asp-net-proj) that also discussed the simillar situation, but I couldn't understand the resolution for this. I want this to happen even with Visual Studio Debugging.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had to put code for displaying 404 error in my custom URLRewrite module. Where I handled all extension less URLs & finally at the end where url has been checked for all cases, I rendered 404 Error page, as that url was not meant for my website.

Thanks